# How do I sort a varchar column using numeric ordering

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the field `receiptno`, which is a varchar holding a numeric value, and want to sort this. Sorting as a string gives me the wrong ordering.  I'd like to try sorting it as an integer.  Is there anyway to converting to integer in the order by clause so I can sort by integer in the query itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cast` or `convert` to convert the field type:

`... ORDER BY CAST(receiptno AS INTEGER) ASC`

**Edit** sorry, fixed syntax

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In mysql cast function integer have problem, so i used signed. now working. ORDER BY CAST(receiptno AS SIGNED) ASC - working properly

Answer (score 1):

So, change the type of this column